# Facebook like button not posting to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button at the top of this website: [Click here](http://www.pbjpublishing.com/app/hansel-and-gretel/)

When you click on the button, you successfully like the page, but the "post to facebook" feature doesn't work. The modal window just stays there.

This worked fine until I made some changes to the site the other day, but even after I removed those changes, the "post to facebook" problem persisted.

I've tried debugging the page, but to no avail. I thought perhaps facebook had been punishing the website for messing with the like button so much, but I'm not sure if that's even something facebook does.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine. I clicked like and it showed up on the users profile page:
http://cl.ly/image/2Q2k3z3W3E0l

I put in a status and shared it. It also shows on Facebook:
http://cl.ly/image/3c1R412x021d

I'm not seeing any issues.

Comment: Hmm... seems like you're correct. Looks like most likely my IP address got banned for some reason. Thanks for the answer.